# Array to string conversion using laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I am trying to insert data but unfortunately i am getting error  **Array to string conversion** please help me how can i resolve that thanks.

please check error **https://flareapp.io/share/x5Mznjem**

**return request**

```
{
"_token": "3qLsIoNwWiOuze8aurlSQGqU4FsgttXgY6sMFYnw",
"icon": "0AKj2DRZii6yhJsoWKLNUbmOWKrXzOqKoFJTF4LI.jpg",
"name": "fdgdfg",
"person_name": "dfg",
"contact_number": "43543543",
"city": [
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5"
],
"location": [
"1",
"3",
"4"
],
"address": "A-232 Gulshan-e-hadeed ph 2"
}
```

**controller**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {   
            // return $request->all();
        $request->validate([
            'name' => "required",
            'icon' => 'nullable',
            'person_name' => 'required',
            'contact_number' => 'required',

        ]);

        $agency = Agency::create($request->except('_token'));
            
            

        foreach ($request->city as  $key => $value) {
               
            $agencyCityLocation = new AgencyCityLocation;
            $agencyCityLocation->agency_id = $agency->id;
            $agencyCityLocation->city_id = $value;
            $agencyCityLocation->location_id = $request->location;
            $agencyCityLocation->save();
        }

        return redirect()->route('agency');
    }
```

Comment: `$agencyCityLocation->location_id = $request->location;`  here you need to send id but your sending array

Comment: i am selecting multiple location and city i am sending ids of city and location

Comment: $agencyCityLocation->save(); i am getting error in this line

Comment: if your selecting `multiple location` then your database need to allow to insert array insted of single id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
$agencyCityLocation->location_id = $request->location;
```

By

```
$agencyCityLocation->location_id = $request->location[$key]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this line:

```
$agencyCityLocation->location_id = $request->location;
```

As you wrote `$request->location` is an array...

```
"location": [
   "1",
   "3",
   "4"
],
```

...and I assume, that in `$agencyCityLocation->location_id` only one string is expected and not an array.

One solution would be to iterate through the locations as well (as you do with the cities), but actually we don't know how you want to save your data into the database. Do you want one DB entry for each city - location combination or is the city combined with the location?

Comment: is this solution ?

Comment: We don't know how the OP wants to handle this situation. He needs to iterate through all locations and all cities. We don't know, if he wants to create one DB entry for each city and location combination. But I will add this explantion to my answer.